# XML DOM. Get element by name on first child level

Tags: plsql, xmldom

I have such xml:

```
<root>
  <element1>
     <doc>2</doc>
  </element1>
  <doc>1</doc>
</root>
```

I want to get element on first child level after root element (value = 1). If I do it through nodelist (pl/sql version of xmldom api):

```
nl := getElementsByTagName(rootnode,'doc');
len := xmldom.getLength(nl);
IF LEN>0 THEN
    N:=xmldom.item(nl, 0);
END IF;
RETURN N;
```

first element in list would be element with value = 2. How could I process only through child nodes of first child level without looping through elements?

Answer (score 2):

With [DBMS_XMLDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_xmldom.htm) use [GETCHILDRENBYTAGNAME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_xmldom.htm#i1122111):

```
declare
  xml constant xmltype := xmltype(
'<root>
  <element1>
     <doc>2 - two</doc>
  </element1>
  <doc>1 - one</doc>
</root>'
);
  doc constant dbms_xmldom.domdocument := dbms_xmldom.newdomdocument(xml);

  root_elem constant dbms_xmldom.domelement :=
    dbms_xmldom.getdocumentelement(doc);

  doc_nodes constant dbms_xmldom.domnodelist :=
    dbms_xmldom.getchildrenbytagname(root_elem, 'doc');
begin
  declare
    last_index constant pls_integer := dbms_xmldom.getlength(doc_nodes) - 1;
    node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
    text_node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
  begin
    for i in 0 .. last_index loop
      node := dbms_xmldom.item(doc_nodes, i);
      text_node := dbms_xmldom.getfirstchild(node);
      dbms_output.put_line('i = ' || i ||
                           ' name = ' || dbms_xmldom.getnodename(node) ||
                           ' type = ' || dbms_xmldom.getnodetype(node) ||
                           ' text = ' || dbms_xmldom.getnodevalue(text_node));
    end loop;
  end;
end;
/
```

Output:

```
SQL> @so24
i = 0 name = doc type = 1 text = 1 - one

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I see you using LOOP, which I asked to avoid. But I can't figure out, why do you get result on first iteration (i = 0)

Comment: @AndreyKhataev: I'm looping because `getchildrenbytagname` returns `domnodelist` - the number of nodes in the list can be anything. If you really want just the first node from the list you can use the same technique than in your question. The difference between `getelementsbytagname` and `getchildrenbytagname` is that the first returns elements on all sublevels (`root/element1/doc` and `root/doc`) but the latter returns only the child elements (`root/doc`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xslprocessor package, and then find the right node using XPath:

```
nl := xslprocessor.selectnodes(rootnode, 'root/doc');
len := xmldom.getLength(nl);
IF LEN>0 THEN
    N:=xmldom.item(nl, 0);
END IF;
RETURN N;
```